# pyspark partitioning create an extra empty file for every partition

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, parquet, partitioning

I am facing with one problem in Azure Databricks. In my notebook I am executing simple write command with partitioning:

```
df.write.format('parquet').partitionBy("startYear").save(output_path,header=True)
```

And I see something like this: [image]

Can someone explain why spark is creating this additional empty files for every partition and how to disable it?

I tried different mode for write, different partitioning and spark versions

Comment: `partitionBy` and number of partitions (e.g. number of output files) are not similar. If you need just one file, you should repartition your data before writing (e.g. `df.repartition(1)`).

Comment: @Darkstorm, Is your storage account is of type ADLS or Blob Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the above and got the same results when I use Blob Storage.

[image]

> Can someone explain why spark is creating this additional empty files
> for every partition and how to disable it?

Spark won't create these types of files. **Blob Storage creates the blobs like above when we create parquet files by partitions**.

We cannot avoid these if you use Blob Storage. **You can avoid it by using ADLS Storage**.

**These are my Results with ADLS:**

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you for explanation